# Where is the Form/Report `Menu` event (that relates to OnMenu) defined in Access?

Tags: ms-access, events, vba

Access Forms and Reports support an `OnMenu` property, that follows the naming convention and behavior of other Form/Report event properties like `OnLoad` (where assigning the `OnLoad` property a value of `[Event Procedure]` will cause the `Load` event to be handled by the code-behind with signature `Private Sub Report_Load()`).

However, while the `Load` event and its `OnLoad` property are easily identifiable in the Object Browser and in the Form/Report properties dialog, the same is not the case with `OnMenu`. The `OnMenu` property *is* in Object Browser, but it <s>does not appear to be</s> is in the Properties dialog as "Menu Bar", and the `Menu` event is nowhere to be seen. But if I assign the name of a public function to the `OnMenu` property, then the function is called when I open the report:

```
Report_Report1.OnMenu = "=MyOnMenuCallback()"
```

But I also see there is a `MenuBar` property, which seems to have the *same* value that I assigned to `OnMenu`....

**EDIT:** There also appears to be a `ShortcutMenuBar` property which fires an event, but the event is not visible in Object Browser, and there doesn't seem to be an `OnShortcutMenu` property?

Where is this `Menu` event defined? I can't find anything in the Object Browser other than the `OnMenu` property. Is it a *real* event that I can write an event handler for (if I assign the `OnMenu` property a value of `[Event Procedure]`?

Answer (score 1):

The `OnMenu` property is essentially deprecated in Access 2.0 and higher and is shown in the Object Browser for backwards compatibility with Access 1.x only.  It was never an Event, it is a property.  In Microsoft Access 1.x, you created special Macros to define your custom drop down menus and menu items and then set the `OnMenu` property to that Macro name.  In Access 2.0 through Access 2003, you would either create the same kind of custom menu Macros, or create menubars or toolbars using the GUI and assign them to the `MenuBar` property.  In Access 2007 and above, the proper method of providing custom menus or toolbars in your application is to create [custom Ribbons](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Customize-the-Ribbon-45e110b9-531c-46ed-ab3a-4e25bc9413de) using Ribbon XML and putting in the USysRibbons table.

The online documentation for many version of Access are misleading and incorrect for the `OnMenu` entry.  For example, looking at this [MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213956(v=office.11).aspx), it would lead you to believe that OnMenu was a Form or Report event, but it isn't, and the one piece of information that is missing in that documentation is "how" the Event is triggered, because it isn't an event.  Click on the links there for some of the actual Form events, and you will notice they are almost the same kind of entry, but they include the crucial statement:

> The XXX event occures when ...

The documentation for `OnMenu` is simply wrong (sadly, as is the case with too many bits of Microsoft Documentation).

Think of `OnMenu` as being renamed to `MenuBar` in Access 2.0 and higher, which is why if you set it in code, it appears in the `MenuBar` entry in the GUI properties dialog.